# Searching a lot of keywords on twitter via tweepy

Tags: python-3.x, twitter, python-3.7, tweepy, keyword

I am trying to make a python code with `tweepy` that will track all the tweets from a specific country from a date which will have some of the chosen specific keywords. And I have chosen a lot of keywords like 24-25.

My keywords are `vigilance anticipation interesting ecstacy joy serenity admiration trust acceptance terror fear apprehensive amazement surprize distraction grief sadness pensiveness loathing disgust boredom rage anger annoyance`.

for more understanding, my code till now is:

```
places = api.geo_search(query="Canada",granularity="country")
place_id = places[0].id

public_tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.search,
              q="place:"+place_id+" since:2020-03-01",
              lang="en",
              ).items(num_tweets)
```

Please help me with this question as soon as possible.

Thank You

Comment: The Search API that tweepy uses by default can only provide Tweets from the past 7 days. In order to get Tweets from March you’ll need to use the Premium Full-Archive search, which is different.

Comment: I did solved that problem with the default version as in the query section, I wrote some commands of advanced searches in twitter. Like, if you use Twitter, you'll know that if you type "since: 1 march 2020", you get all the tweets from that date. Currently my main problems is that how I am gonna search for 24 keyword in twitter with the API. If you know how to solve that, please do reply .